# Merge rows into List for similar values in SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, merge, tablerow

Spark version 2.0.2.6 and Scala Version 2.11.11

I am having the following csv file.

```
sno name    number
1   hello   1
1   hello   2
2   hai 12
2   hai 22
2   hai 32
3   how 43
3   how 44
3   how 45
3   how 46
4   are 33
4   are 34
4   are 45
4   are 44
4   are 43
```

I want output as:

```
sno name    number
1   hello   [1,2]
2   hai [12,22,32]
3   how [43,44,45,46]
4   are [33,34,44,45,43]
```

Order of the elements in the list is not important.

Using dataframes or RDD's which ever is appropriate.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Could you please show what have you tried?

Comment: I read it using dataframes. I know how to groupby. but I am not aware of how to merge the row values into one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df.groupBy("sno", "name").agg(collect_list("number").alias("number")).sort("sno").show()
+---+-----+--------------------+
|sno| name|              number|
+---+-----+--------------------+
|  1|hello|              [1, 2]|
|  2|  hai|        [12, 22, 32]|
|  3|  how|    [43, 44, 45, 46]|
|  4|  are|[33, 34, 45, 44, 43]|
+---+-----+--------------------+
```